Qualtrics: implementing a dice task with javascript
I'm implementing a survey on Qualtrics and I'm trying to use a 'simple javascript' with these aims in mind:

ppl clicks on the image of a couple of dice
random generated number appears on the screen and get registered on a column of the dataset. The same thing goes in two different blocks
link between the dice image and the javascript is implemented through an HTML script

HTML code implementing the dice image on the question
<title></title>
<div class="container">
<p id="instruction">This is a trial task.<br>
 INSTRUCTION HERE NOT WRITTEN FOR SAKE OF BREVITY </p>

<div><button id="diceButton"><img width="150" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;" src="https://uniapsico.eu.qualtrics.com/ControlPanel/Graphic.php?IM=IM_Rp12uTWTqk2W7a8" height="150" alt="Dadi"></button>

<p id="result">&nbsp;</p>
</div>

Javascript code: roll the dice, return a number on screen, record the number on a column of the final dataset
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function() {
    var diceButton = document.getElementById('diceButton');
    var resultField = document.getElementById('result');
    var instructionText = document.getElementById('instruction'); // reference to instruction 

    // Style
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = `
        #result {
            font-size: 30px; /* Dimension of written text */
        }

        #result .number {
            font-weight: bold; /* Number made in bold*/
            font-size: 34px; /* Text size*/
            color: black; /* Color of the text */
        }
    `;
    document.head.appendChild(style);

    diceButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const result = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 4; // Generate a random integer between 4 and 12
        resultField.innerHTML = `You rolled a <span class="number">${result}</span>!`;

        // Save the result in a column on the final dataset 
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('Risultato_trial', result);
    });
});

The same code appears twice in the survey, with minor modifications. On of them regards the name column where the result is stored.
It seems that when I preview the question, everything works correctly. But if I preview the block it doesn't, and if I publish the survey the same happens, and moreover it doesn't record the presumed launch on some new column on the dataset.
Anybody has a clue? Qualtrics helpdesk couldn't help me, nor the community.
Thank you very much

In that case, the existence of more than 1 question on same page causes the issue. There will be a few dices with same id and the following line won't work as expected.
var diceButton = document.getElementById('diceButton');

The correct approach:
Attribute id must be unique. Use a CSS class instead. Instead of document.getElementById use HTMLElement.querySelectorAll which will return a NodeList which you can iterate.
Example:


var resultField = document.getElementById("result")

document.querySelectorAll(".diceButton").forEach(function(diceButton) {

  // do something with each button

  diceButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const result = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 4; // Generate a random integer between 4 and 12
    resultField.innerHTML = `You rolled a <span class="number">${result}</span>!`;

    // Save the result in a column on the final dataset 
    // Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('Risultato_trial', result);
  });
})
<div><button class="diceButton"><img width="150" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;" src="https://uniapsico.eu.qualtrics.com/ControlPanel/Graphic.php?IM=IM_Rp12uTWTqk2W7a8" height="150" alt="Dadi"></button>
</div>
<div><button class="diceButton"><img width="150" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;" src="https://uniapsico.eu.qualtrics.com/ControlPanel/Graphic.php?IM=IM_Rp12uTWTqk2W7a8" height="150" alt="Dadi"></button>
</div>

<div><button class="diceButton"><img width="150" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;" src="https://uniapsico.eu.qualtrics.com/ControlPanel/Graphic.php?IM=IM_Rp12uTWTqk2W7a8" height="150" alt="Dadi"></button>
</div>


<p id="result">&nbsp;</p>



Notice that if you have a .result for each question, which is probably the case, you would need to get the matching .result for your .diceButton which is possible using the DOM knowing they must have a common ancestor, the question. Change classes as needed.
var result = diceButton.closest('.question').querySelector('.result')


thx man I' m not sure I understood everything but the main point that is clear to me is that if I cut-off one of the trials the other one should work properly?

If I'm correct then, yes, that's a possible solution

Unfortunately cutting-off one of the trials didn't work.

is there a related error in the console?

Unfortunately no. If Qualtrics has a console I'm not aware of it.

your browser DevTools have a console (press F12)
